# c# crystal report export error

Tags: c#

i have tried to export the crystal report to pdf format. but i go the error like 'System.IO.MemoryStream' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'..... ANd this is my code, please verify it and correct me..

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MemoryStream MS;
        MS = (MemoryStream);
        MR.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.BinaryWrite(MS.ToArray());
        Response.End();


    }
```

Comment: that code doesn't compile....

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the line

`MS = (MemoryStream);`

You seem to be missing something here. Are you trying to cast something to memorystream, if so what?

If you want to construct an MemoryStream obj you need to use something like

`MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(100)`

Note that MemoryStream implments IDisposable so you probably want to wrap it in a using clause.

Comment: again got this error : "The method or operation is not implemented." in my class file friend